# Regexp replace solution in hive to mask first 6 characters

Tags: regex, string, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

Trying to mask the first 6 characters in hive using the `regexp_replace`. But, not able to achieve a solution.

Input :

```
123-45-6789
```

Output :

```
###-##-6789
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are flexible using other characters other than `#` to mask the string, you could use an in-built masking function [`mask_show_last_n`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DataMaskingFunctions).

```
select mask_show_last_n('123-45-6789',4)
```

Output would be `nnn-nn-6789` as `n` is used to mask numbers by default in these masking functions.

Answer (score 2):

Get substring of first 6 characters and replace in it everything except `-`, then concatenate with the rest of the string:

```
select regexp_replace(substr('123-45-6789',1,6),'[^-]','#')||substr('123-45-6789',7)
```

Result:

```
###-##-6789
```

For Hive version < 2.2.0 use concat instead of || operator:

```
select concat( regexp_replace(substr('123-45-6789',1,6),'[^-]','#'), substr('123-45-6789',7))
```